# Liquid and Arithmetic

Tags: pagination, jekyll, liquid

I am working on some pagination and I am wondering if there is a way to tell liquid to only show 5 pages.  The output I am looking for is

<< First 5 6 **7** 8 9 Last >>

The logic I currently have in place works but it is showing all 30 some pages.

```
{% for count in (2..paginator.total_pages) %}
    {% if count == paginator.page %}
        <span class="current">{{ count }}</span>
    {% else %}
        <a href="/page/{{ count }}/" class="pagenavi-page" title="{{ count }}">{{ count }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to be able to make the 2 and paginator.total_pages be dynamic, I have tried

```
{% for count in ((paginator.page - 2)..(paginator.page + 2)) %}
```

This code however does not actually do the math, if paginator.page = 5 then the loop is 5..5 and does not provide the expected results.  I can figure out the logic so that it does not hit negative numbers and works as expected but how can I do math equations in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use a filter on `paginator.total_pages` to do the arithmetic, and then capture the result in a variable using the `capture` tag. Once you have the start and end pages, you can write the `for` loop as you normally would:

```
{% capture page_start %}{{ paginator.page | minus: 2 }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture page_end %}{{ paginator.page | plus: 2 }}{% endcapture %}

{% for count in (page_start..page_end) %}
     {% comment %} ... do your thing ... {% endcomment %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer it makes sense.  I do however find myself against another error when trying to setup my looping.  I do need to be able to check to see if page_end is greater than the total pages.

    {% if page_end > paginator.total_pages %}
      {% assign page_end = paginator.total_pages %}
    {% endif %}

The above code gives me the following error

    Liquid Exception: comparison of String with 37 failed in index.html

Is there a way to do this in Liquid?

Comment: I figured this out, just had to extend the pagination.rb in Jekyll and add the pager_start and pager_end variables and calculations

Comment: For Googlers looking for a more modern, GitHub Pages compatible approach that doesn't involve Ruby programming, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31972386/5195629). Disclosure: I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a blog with Jekyll and I've faced a similar situation. According to what I've found in the [Liquid wiki](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#for-loops) is possible to iterate over a subset of a given collection using `limit` and `offset`.

The following example reflects your particular case and *should* work correctly in every page, from the first to the last one:

```
{% capture start %}{{ paginator.page | minus: 3 }}{% endcapture %}

{% for i in (1..paginator.total_pages) limit: 5 offset: start %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Bootstrap 3.0.3 for my website. I use the following code for pagination.
It has the same effect you're looking for. The code I posted above is what you're looking for, but I will post my bootstrap pagination code here anyways.

```
{% if paginator.total_pages != 1 %} 
{% if paginator.total_pages < 7 %}
        <div class="page-body col-md-12">
          <ul class="pagination pagination-centered">
            {% if paginator.total_pages >= 10 %} 
            {% if paginator.previous_page %}
                <li>
                  <a href="{{ site.url }}/">&laquo;&laquo;</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
              <li class="disabled">
                <a>&laquo;&laquo;</a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if paginator.previous_page %}
              {% if paginator.previous_page == 1 %}
                <li>
                  <a href="{{ site.url }}/">&laquo;</a>
                </li>
              {% else %}
                <li>
                  <a href="{{ site.url }}/page{{paginator.previous_page}}">&laquo;</a>
                </li>
              {% endif %}
            {% else %}
              <li class="disabled">
                <a>&laquo;</a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if paginator.page == 1 %}
              <li class="active">
                <a>1</a>
              </li>
            {% else %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ site.url }}/">1</a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% for count in (2..paginator.total_pages) %}
              {% if count == paginator.page %}
                <li class="active">
                  <a>{{count}}</a>
                </li>
              {% else %}
                <li>
                  <a href="{{ site.url }}/page{{count}}">{{count}}</a>
                </li>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if paginator.next_page %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ site.url }}/page{{paginator.next_page}}">&raquo;</a>
              </li>
            {% else %}
              <li class="disabled">
                <a>&raquo;</a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if paginator.total_pages >= 10 %} 
            {% if paginator.next_page %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ site.url }}/page{{paginator.total_pages}}">&raquo;&raquo;</a>
              </li>
            {% else %}
              <li class="disabled">
                <a>&raquo;&raquo;</a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
{% else %}

{% assign page_start = paginator.page | minus: 2 %}
{% assign page_end = paginator.page | plus: 2 %}
{% if page_end > paginator.total_pages %}
{% assign page_end = paginator.total_pages %}
{% assign page_start = paginator.page | minus: 4 %}
{% endif %}
{% if page_start < 2 %}
{% assign page_end = paginator.page | plus: 3 %}
{% assign page_start = paginator.page | minus: 1 %}
{% endif %}
{% if page_start == 0 %}
{% assign page_end = paginator.page | plus: 4 %}
{% assign page_start = paginator.page %}
{% endif %}

<div class="page-body col-md-12">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-centered">
    {% if paginator.total_pages > 5 %} 
    {% if paginator.previous_page %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ site.url }}/">&laquo;&laquo;</a>
        </li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled">
        <a>&laquo;&laquo;</a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if paginator.previous_page %}
      {% if paginator.previous_page == 1 %}
        <li>
          <a href="/">&laquo;</a>
        </li>
      {% else %}
        <li>
          <a href="/page{{paginator.previous_page}}">&laquo;</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled">
        <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if page_start == 1 %}
    {% assign page_end = paginator.page | plus: 4 %}
    {% assign page_start = 2 %}
    {% if paginator.page == 1 %}
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">1</a>
      </li>
    {% else %}
      <li>
        <a href="/">1</a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% for count in (page_start..page_end) %}
      {% if count == paginator.page %}
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">{{count}}</a>
        </li>
      {% else %}
        <li>
          <a href="/page{{count}}">{{count}}</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if paginator.next_page %}
      <li>
        <a href="/page{{paginator.next_page}}">&raquo;</a>
      </li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled">
        <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if paginator.total_pages > 5 %} 
    {% if paginator.next_page %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ site.url }}/page{{paginator.total_pages}}">&raquo;&raquo;</a>
      </li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled">
        <a>&raquo;&raquo;</a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
{% if paginator.total_pages < 7 %}
{% if paginator.page == 1 %}
        <span class="current bold">1</span>
{% else %}
        <a href="{{ site.url }}/">1</a>
{% endif %}
{% for count in (2..paginator.total_pages) %}
    {% if count == paginator.page %}
        <span class="current bold">{{ count }}</span>
    {% else %}
        <a href="/page{{ count }}/" class="pagenavi-page" title="{{ count }}">{{ count }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
{% assign page_start = paginator.page | minus: 2 %}
{% assign page_end = paginator.page | plus: 2 %}
{% if page_end > paginator.total_pages %}
{% assign page_end = paginator.total_pages %}
{% assign page_start = paginator.page | minus: 4 %}
{% endif %}
{% if page_start < 2 %}
{% assign page_end = paginator.page | plus: 3 %}
{% assign page_start = paginator.page | minus: 1 %}
{% endif %}
{% if page_start == 0 %}
{% assign page_end = paginator.page | plus: 4 %}
{% assign page_start = paginator.page %}
{% endif %}
{% if page_start == 1 %}
{% assign page_end = paginator.page | plus: 4 %}
{% assign page_start = 2 %}
{% if paginator.page == 1 %}
        <span class="current bold">1</span>
{% else %}
        <a href="{{ site.url }}/">1</a>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% for count in (page_start..page_end) %}
    {% if count == paginator.page %}
        <span class="current bold">{{ count }}</span>
    {% else %}
        <a href="/page{{ count }}/" class="pagenavi-page" title="{{ count }}">{{ count }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```