# Why doesn't arithmetic work on variables

Tags: ruby, pagination, jekyll, liquid

I'm stuck getting a basic if statement to work on a custom pagination for a jekyll site. Here's my code:

```
{% if paginator.total_pages > 1 %}
  {% for page in (1..paginator.total_pages) %}
    {% if page == paginator.page %}
      ({{ page }})
    {% elsif page >= 6 and page <= 10 %}
      {{ page }}
    {% else %}
      {{ paginator.page }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Assuming the current page is number 8, I get the following output:

```
8 8 8 8 8 6 7 (8) 9 10 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Now if I replace `{% elsif page >= 6 and page <= 10 %}` with `{% elsif page >= (paginator.page - 2) and page <= (paginator.page + 2) %}` I get the following output:

```
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 (8) 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Can someone explain why basic arithmetic doesn't work on the variable (`paginator.page`) and how I can get around this?

Comment: I suspect that the laws of arithmetic are fine and that you instead have an issue in the logic of your statements.  Have you tried printing the values of page and paginator.page anywhere outside the structs above to verify that they are what you think they are?

Comment: Like what I did on line 8? I know the value is 8 because it prints 16 times, and it's the 8th page so it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OK, total rewrite of my answer, I'll leave the old stuff below for historical reference to the troubleshooting steps.**

According to this: [Liquid and Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025597/liquid-and-arithmetic) Liquid has it's own way of capturing variables and doing arithmetic. Thanks to the OP for the find. Just surprised that I couldn't find this in their own documentation.

---

OK, since Liquid apparently needs `and`, not `&&` I would try getting the arithmetic out of the if statement.

```
{% for page in (1..paginator.total_pages) %}
{% assign two_less = (paginator.page - 2) %}
{% assign two_more = (paginator.page + 2) %}
{% if page == paginator.page %}
  ({{ page }})
{% elsif page >= two_less and page <= two_more %}
      {{ page }}
...
```

---

I think you might be seeing a problem with the Liquid template language. There have been problems before with `and` in Liquid, even in strings. See this closed issue: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/13

I would try this:

```
{% elsif (page >= (paginator.page - 2)) && (page <= (paginator.page + 2)) %}
```

`and` and `&&` are slightly different in ruby, and possibly Liquid has some special significance for `and`.

---

**old answer**

It is basically doing exactly what you tell it to do. You say in the comments "I know the value is 8 because it prints 16 times". That is not valid debugging. All you know is that

```
page = 8 #at the time of execution
```

and that your `if` statement determined that it needed to print that value every time. So you are assuming that "8" is coming from the various branches of your `if` statement, but it is far more likely that your `if` statement keeps evaluating to the branch that prints "8". The simplest debugging you can do here is add:

```
{% if paginator.total_pages > 1 %}
  {% for page in (1..paginator.total_pages) %}
    {% if page == paginator.page %}
      ({{ page }})
      {{ puts "if" }}
    {% elsif page >= (paginator.page - 2) and page <= (paginator.page + 2) %}
      {{ page }}
      {{ puts "else if" }}
    {% else %}
      {{ paginator.page }}
      {{ puts "else" }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I don't use Jekyll so I am not 100% sure of my syntax, but you see what I'm trying to achieve? This will tell you where in the `if` statement your output value is coming from. If it is coming from the arithmetic as you suspect, it will tell you that. What I suspect though, is that you will see it never gets into that part of the `if` as you assume. Also, I'm not sure why you are getting

```
8 8 8 8 8 6 7 (8) 9 10 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Do you want the first five and the last seven elements to evaluate to `8` and not:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 (8) 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

Also just to be sure you're getting the type of variable return you expect change

```
(paginator.page - 2) and page <= (paginator.page + 2)
```

to:

```
(paginator.page.to_i - 2) and page <= (paginator.page.to_i + 2)
```

So my answer is pretty much what mcfinnigan said, arithmetic with variables does work. So you are either not getting an integer from the method `paginator.page`, or there is some other flaw in the `if` statement's logic.

**edit**-----
(removed part about "paginator.number" as it doesn't seem to apply to user's case)

I can expand and improve this answer if you can do the debugging I suggested and post the output.

Comment: First I'll start with I want the output to be `8 8 8 8 8 6 7 (8) 9 10 8 8 8 8 8 8 8` without hardcoding the numbers `6` and `10`. The output to your code confirms that paginator.page is 8. Output: `8 else 8 else 8 else 8 else 8 else 8 else 8 else (8) if 8 else 8 else 8 else 8 else 8 else 8 else 8 else 8 else 8 else`. Also adding `.to_i` didn't work / same result. Also the doc says `paginator.page` but I tried `paginator.number ` and it didn't work / same result.

Comment: OK, a few questions; is this rails? What version of Ruby? Rails, which pagination gem are you using? Did the debug output you posted above come from the code using '(paginator.page - 2) and page <= (paginator.page + 2)'? If so, you notice that the `elsif` never evaluates to true. I'm wondering if it is a precedence problem in how you've crafted your `and` statement. `and` in ruby is a control flow operator. I think you need `&&` try:`elsif (page >= (paginator.page - 2)) && (page <= (paginator.page + 2))`

Comment: You may not need all of the parentheses but use them to start so you know you are getting the precedence you are expecting. You can always test removing them later. Though they make for easier reading on first glance.

Comment: As far as I know it's ruby version `ruby 2.0.0p247`. I'm using the Jekyll paginator, and haven't installed any additional gems. Your code results in: `8 8 8 8 8 8 8 (8) 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17` which looks like it just ignores the second statement. I believe Jekyll uses `and`

Comment: I think you must be seeing some edge case of Ruby/Jekyll/Liquid. Not surprising as your are using several technologies that are layered on each other. I believe Jekyll uses the Liquid template language, which is based in Ruby but seems to make some changes. I would submit your issue to them as a bug. In the meantime, can you assign `paginator.page - 2` and `paginator.page + 2` to variables, then use the variables in your comparison?

Comment: Can you tell which version of Liquid you are on?

Comment: Still not working. It looks like arithmetic just doesn't work. `{% assign low = (paginator.page - 2) %}` `{% assign high = (paginator.page + 2) %}` `{{ low }} {{ high }}` results in `8 8` instead of `6 10`. At this point I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be able to do arithmetic, but it's such a vital feature to be missing. Versions: `jekyll (1.4.3)` `liquid (2.5.5)`

Comment: I would actually open this as an issue with Liquid https://github.com/Shopify/liquid either they need some documentation (I've done some searching and their documentation is pretty lacking) on it not being available, or it's a bug. I get why Liquid is used, it's really meant for non-programmers to be able to "program" content. But simple variable arithmetic seems like something they should include.

Comment: Turns out this is a duplicate of another question, and I need to use Capture `{% capture page_start %}{{ paginator.page | minus: 2 }}{% endcapture %}` and `{% capture page_start %}{{ paginator.page | plus: 2 }}{% endcapture %}`. If you want to update your answer with a link to the answer I'll accept and up-vote for your help. Thank you. [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025597/liquid-and-arithmetic)